# Is this gain calculated correctly?

Tags: differential, differential-amplifier

In this schematic, if the T5 transistor is off and the T4 is on, what would be the incremental resistances ri3 , ro3.

[image]

my guess is that:

ri3 is :

rPi4 + RE5 + Rspeaker.

and ro3 is :

RE5*(B+1) + rPi4

Is this correct?

Comment: Your solution is correct

Comment: @G362 can you help me is this noob problem, :D

Comment: @MiguelSilvestre It might be time for you to check out the [tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: ri3 = r_pi4 + (B + 1)*(RE5 + Rspeaker). ro3 = RE5 + (r_pi4 +RC3)/(B+1)